# Overlapping two images while checking the transparent pixels android

Tags: android, image, overlay, transparent

Below is the code I am using to overlapping two images.

```
public static Bitmap overlay(String patho,String patht) {
    Bitmap bmp1= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(patho);
    Bitmap bmp2= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(patht);
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);

    Matrix m=new Matrix();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, m, null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, m,null);


 return bmOverlay;
}
```

Using the above code snippet I can easily merge two image or overlap them on each other. Below is what I actually want to achieve:

1. I have two images overlapping them. **Bottom image** is a full colored image while **Top image** has some transparent area.
2. I want to merge both image while still keeping the transparent area from the top image in final image which I will get after merging them?
   Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!
Please **Note** that I need to keep that transparent area in final image from top Image while erasing the same pixels from below image too.
I have two images below first one is top one and second one is bottom one.
[image]

Now this is what will come in bottom.
[image]
What i want is to eliminate the above picture transparent pixels from the bottom blurred picture and merge them.

Comment: i am seening any transparent area in any image.

Comment: @Sohail Zahid basically above apple image is totally transparent, I think this has given you the idea what i want to achieve.

Comment: If u have ever worked on Picture in picture effect i am trying to achieve that

Comment: i got your point my answer cant do that it just for pasting image on each other sory.

Comment: what you are saying in not transparency?

Comment: okay thanks for your help i will keep working on it then